# pandas getting nth to last day of month

Tags: python, pandas

Given a DataFrame of intraday data:

```
                          Open       High        Low       Last     Volume  No. Trades   Close Bid  No. Bids   Close Ask  No. Asks
Timestamp                                                                                                                         
1996-01-02 09:30:00        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN   61.375000       1.0   61.406250       1.0
1996-01-02 09:31:00   61.40625   61.40625   61.40625   61.40625     4100.0         1.0         NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN
1996-01-02 09:32:00   61.40625   61.40625   61.40625   61.40625      100.0         1.0   61.375000       2.0   61.406250       2.0
1996-01-02 09:33:00        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN   61.406250       2.0   61.437500       2.0
1996-01-02 09:35:00        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN   61.390625       1.0   61.421875       1.0
```

How can I select the days that are n days away from the end of the month? I want to use groupby() but I am not sure how when it comes to intraday data, because I have more than just daily values in my index.

```
def select_days(data, n_days, rtn = ''):

    ### select business days
    ts_days = pd.to_datetime(data.index.date)
    businessDays = pd.bdate_range(start=data.index[0].date(), end=data.index[-1].date())
    data = data[ts_days.isin(businessDays)]

    ### select T-n days     
    data[(data.index.days_in_month - data.index.day)==n_days]
    return data
```

Comment: Could you provide the code to reproduce the dataset?

Comment: It's reading from a csv, you can just copy paste that into a csv, delimit by spaces and read it using pandas.

Comment: I'm looking to help you.  Please provide the data in a way I can copy and paste and have your exact dataframe to work with.

Answer (score 0):

To generalize this over a dataset with multiple months, I would groupby days from the end of the month, and select the group you want. The trick is that you can't just select days of a specific number, since the date of the last day varies from month to month.

```
from calendar import monthrange

def days_until_end(date):
    _, last_day = monthrange(date.year, date.month)
    return last_day - date.day

df.groupby(days_until_end).get_group(N)
```

Where `N` is the number of days before the end of the month you want to target.

Comment: A little unfamiliar with groupby.. how does that function acquire the parameter 'date' in the call?

Comment: `.groupby` calls its argument, `days_until_end` with the index of each row

Comment: It does not seem to be referencing the index properly.. `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'month'`

Comment: Without seeing your code, we can't help. Please edit a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code into your post.

Comment: There is no code to share. I'm running exactly what you wrote here on the DF.

Comment: Would it be possible to groupby the last day of the month, then shift by -n?

Comment: If you were only running my code, you'd get an error because `df` would be undefined. What about the code that loaded your csv into a datframe?

Answer (score 0):

No need for a `groupby` here. First get a series that tells you the days in the month for that particular row:

```
days_in_month = df.index.daysinmonth
```

Next get a series that is the day-of-month

```
day_of_month = df.index.day
```

Now you can simply do:

```
df[(days_in_month - day_of_month).to_series().between(0, n_days)]
```

Where `n_days` is your parameter.

Comment: doesn't seem like the difference of those two vectors has a .between function.. `AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'between'`

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois Just edited. Added a call to `to_series` to the difference before the call to `between`.

Comment: I see... is it possible to extend this logic to work with business days?

Comment: As in days_in_month includes non-business days... in my case I need to account for that

Answer (score 0):

pandas tricks:

```
df['days_to_month_end'] = df.index.days_in_month - df.index.day
df[df.days_to_month_end==n]
```

or in one line:

```
df[(df.index.days_in_month - df.index.day)==n]
```

Comment: Can this account for business days?